# Hay alguna forma de resumir todos estos else if?

Tags: c++

Buenas, estoy con un proyecto donde una función comprueba si una bola toca un muro, el cual es un array de 15 "porciones" con cada uno de 50u de tamañano. Necesito saber que parte del muro toca y para eso he hecho lo siguiente, pero queda exageradamente aparatoso:

```
if(bolaY == INIPANTALLAY + ALCADAMAO)//Comprueba que llegue hasta la altura del maon
            {   
                if (bolaX > 30 && bolaX < 80)
                {
                    if (Mao[0].maotrencat == false)//Si el maon tocado no esta roto continua
                    {
                        Mao[0].maotrencat = true;//Cambia el estado del maon
                        punts += 1;//Suma 1 punto
                        dirX *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                        dirY *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                    }
                }
                else if (bolaX > 80 && bolaX < 140)
                {

                    if (Mao[1].maotrencat == false)//Si el maon tocado no esta roto continua
                    {
                        Mao[1].maotrencat = true;//Cambia el estado del maon
                        punts += 1;//Suma 1 punto
                        dirX *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                        dirY *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                    }
                }
                else if (bolaX > 140 && bolaX <200)
                {

                    if (Mao[2].maotrencat == false)//Si el maon tocado no esta roto continua
                    {
                        Mao[2].maotrencat = true;//Cambia el estado del maon
                        punts += 1;//Suma 1 punto
                        dirX *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                        dirY *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                    }
                }
                else if (bolaX > 200 && bolaX <260)
                {

                    if (Mao[3].maotrencat == false)//Si el maon tocado no esta roto continua
                    {
                        Mao[3].maotrencat = true;//Cambia el estado del maon
                        punts += 1;//Suma 1 punto
                        dirX *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                        dirY *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                    }
                }
                else if (bolaX > 260 && bolaX <320)
                {

                    if (Mao[4].maotrencat == false)//Si el maon tocado no esta roto continua
                    {
                        Mao[4].maotrencat = true;//Cambia el estado del maon
                        punts += 1;//Suma 1 punto
                        dirX *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                        dirY *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                    }
                }
                else if (bolaX > 320 && bolaX <380)
                {

                    if (Mao[5].maotrencat == false)//Si el maon tocado no esta roto continua
                    {
                        Mao[5].maotrencat = true;//Cambia el estado del maon
                        punts += 1;//Suma 1 punto
                        dirX *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                        dirY *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                    }
                }
                else if (bolaX > 380 && bolaX <440)
                {

                    if (Mao[6].maotrencat == false)//Si el maon tocado no esta roto continua
                    {
                        Mao[6].maotrencat = true;//Cambia el estado del maon
                        punts += 1;//Suma 1 punto
                        dirX *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                        dirY *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                    }
                }
                else if (bolaX > 440 && bolaX <500)
                {

                    if (Mao[7].maotrencat == false)//Si el maon tocado no esta roto continua
                    {
                        Mao[7].maotrencat = true;//Cambia el estado del maon
                        punts += 1;//Suma 1 punto
                        dirX *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                        dirY *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                    }
                }
                else if (bolaX > 500 && bolaX <560)
                {

                    if (Mao[8].maotrencat == false)//Si el maon tocado no esta roto continua
                    {
                        Mao[8].maotrencat = true;//Cambia el estado del maon
                        punts += 1;//Suma 1 punto
                        dirX *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                        dirY *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                    }
                }
                else if (bolaX > 560 && bolaX <620)
                {

                    if (Mao[9].maotrencat == false)//Si el maon tocado no esta roto continua
                    {
                        Mao[9].maotrencat = true;//Cambia el estado del maon
                        punts += 1;//Suma 1 punto
                        dirX *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                        dirY *= -1;// cambio de direccion
                    }
                }
```

He intentado mejorarlo con un Switch, pero no estoy seguro si es posible teniendo en cuenta la comparación y el && en cada caso.

Comment: No se si te ayude y que tanto pueda reducirte tu código, Pero podrias intentar preguntar si esta dentro del area donde no hay muro y despues solo preguntar que muro es.

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices pero no se me ocurre como podría hacer algo así, lo he planteado totalmente al revés, primero comprobar si toca muro y luego si en ese punto exacto continua habiendo un fragmento.

Comment: el primer if es correcto? de 30-80, no debería ser de 20 -80?

Comment: Cierto gracias por el detalle ^^

Comment: @ElPatrón En los IF estas colocando solamente "mayor que" o "menor que"; esta quedando fuera si es igual; ejmplo en el primero con el segundo "if (bolaX > 30 && bolaX < 80)" luego "else if (bolaX > 80 && bolaX < 140)" ¿y si es 80? considero que solo con ">" colocar ">=" o con "<" colocar "<="; espero se entienda. Así con las demas si lo checas dejas fuera un valor.

Comment: Tienes razón, el motivo es que si la bola tocase una parte muy cercana a dos bloques, se destruirían los dos, de ahí que sea <80 para más tarde añadir lo dicho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debes aprovechar que cada porción tiene el mismo tamaño, esa es la **clave**. Entonces podrías utilizar un ciclo for de esta manera:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    if (bolax > 20 + 60*i && bolax < 80 + 60*i)
    {
        if (Mao[i].maotrencat == false)//Si no esta roto continua
        {
            Mao[i].maotrencat = true;//Cambia el estado del maon
            punts += 1;//Suma 1 punto
            dirX *= -1;// cambio de direccion
            dirY *= -1;// cambio de direccion
        }
    break; // este break evita que se siga evaluando todos los otros casos
    // tambien puede servir 
    // i = 15;
    }

}
```

De esta manera tu código queda todo reducido.

Comment: Muy buena implementación, solo dos consideraciones, el primer Mao[0] inicia en 30 hasta 80 son 50 unidades de diferencia para las demas si son 60; y una vez cumpliéndose la condición agregar (antes del final del if) un break ya que sino recorrera todo y si la condición la cumple el primero aún así continua evaluando las demás.

Comment: Gracias por la observación @Roberto León Oramas. :D Por alguna razón, el código mostrado tiene un pequeño fallo, puedes consultar en los comentarios, cuando le consulte sobre esa irregularidad en el primer ciclo si inicia en 20 o 30. con tu permiso, voy a modificar el código para incluir el break que me sugieres. y gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Prueba lo siguiente si da el mismo resultado; veo que lo común es siempre realizar:

```
Mao[INDICEAMODIFICAR].maotrencat = true;
// Las siguientes 3 son simprelas mismas
punts += 1;//Suma 1 punto
dirX *= -1;// cambio de direccion
dirY *= -1;// cambio de direccion
```

Los `if` internos a `if(bolaY == INIPANTALLAY + ALCADAMAO)` de la siguiente forma:

```
int indice=-1; // Iniciado el negativo para indicar ninguno a modificar.

if (bolaX > 30 && bolaX < 80 && (!Mao[0].maotrencat))
{
    indice=0;
}
else if (bolaX > 80 && bolaX < 140 && (!Mao[1].maotrencat))
{

    indice=1;
}
else if (bolaX > 140 && bolaX <200 && (!Mao[2].maotrencat))
{
    indice=2;
}
else if (bolaX > 200 && bolaX <260 && (Mao[3].maotrencat))
{
    indice=3;
}
else if (bolaX > 260 && bolaX <320 && (!Mao[4].maotrencat))
{
    indice=4;
}
else if (bolaX > 320 && bolaX <380 && if (!Mao[5].maotrencat))
{
    indice=5;
}
else if (bolaX > 380 && bolaX <440 && (!Mao[6].maotrencat))
{
    indice=6;
}
else if (bolaX > 440 && bolaX <500 && (!Mao[7].maotrencat))
{
    indice=7;
}
else if (bolaX > 500 && bolaX <560 && (!Mao[8].maotrencat))
{
    indice=8;
}
else if (bolaX > 560 && bolaX <620 && (!Mao[9].maotrencat))
{
    indice=9;
}

if (indice>=0) {
   Mao[indice].maotrencat = true;
   punts += 1;//Suma 1 punto
   dirX *= -1;// cambio de direccion
   dirY *= -1;// cambio de direccion
}
```

Otra forma es que en vez de evaluar `if ([...] && (!Mao[INDICE].maotrencat))` solamente evalues `bolaX` (es la única que veo evaluas) y el `if` que puse donde se evalua indice:

```
if (indice>=0) {
   if (!Mao[indice].maotrencat) {
      Mao[indice].maotrencat = true;
      punts += 1;//Suma 1 punto
      dirX *= -1;// cambio de direccion
      dirY *= -1;// cambio de direccion
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un *array* para obtener el resultado directamente.

No entiendo exactamente como está organizado tu *muro*; por lo que veo en tu código, son trozos de distinto tamaño. Pero, en cualquier caso, todos los trozos son **multiplos** de 10, así que puedes utilizar algo como esto:

```
struct accion_s {
  int Mao;
  int punts;
  int dirX;
  int dirY;
}; 

struct accion_s acciones[620/10] = {
  { W, X, Y, Z },
  { W2, X2, Y2, Z2 },
  { W3, X3, Y3, Z3 },
  ...
};
```

Ahora, tan solo tienes que comprobar una vez:

```
if( bolaY == INIPANTALLAY + ALCADAMAO ) {
  struct accion_s accion = acciones[bolax / 10];

  // Es SEGURO que estamos en el muro.
  Mao[accion.Mao].maotrencat = true;//Cambia el estado del maon.
  punts += accion.punts; //Suma 1 punto
  dirX *= accion.dirX;// cambio de direccion
  dirY *= accion.dirY;// cambio de direccion
}
```

Esto es una técnica *básica* en el desarrollo de juegos: *precalcula* **todo  lo que puedas**.

Comment: La diferencia de tamaño entre los trozos fue un error mio al escribir el código, imagino que al ser todos iguales facilita aún más la tarea. Pero no acabo de entender lo que expones.

Comment: Si son todos iguales, el arreglo es *menor*: `arreglo[NUMERO_DE_TROZOS]`. Luego, tan solo tienes que **dividir** para saber en que trozo estás, y actuar usando los datos que tienes guardados en dicho índice del arreglo.

Answer (score 1):

Después de leer **todos** los comentarios, entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es esto:

Tienes un muro, dividido en varios trozos, y una pelota:

```
------
  o
```

Los trozos con *contiguos*, sin separación. La *coordenada* `X` del primer trozo de muro es `20`. La anchura de todos los trozos es la misma, `60` *pixels*.

Y conoces en todo momento la posición `X` de la pelota.

Para conoces el trozo de muro en el que impactas, **no hay que hacer ningún `if`**. **Te basta con una simple división**.

```
muro = ( pelota.X - 20 ) / 60;
```

Restamos a la posición actual de la pelota el inicio del primer muro, y lo dividimos entre la anchura de los muros; con eso, ya tenemos directamente un índice para tus `Mao[]`.

Puesto que, en todos los casos, haces lo mismo, te bastaría con hacer

```
if( bolaY == INIPANTALLAY + ALCADAMAO ) {
  int idx = ( bolaX - 20 ) / 60;

  if( Mao[idx].maotrencat == false ) {
    Mao[idx].maotrencat = true;
    punts += 1;
    dirX *= -1;
    dirY *= -1;
  }
}
```

En el caso de que tuvieras que realizar **distintas** operaciones dependiendo del muro, es cuando emplearías la solución propuesta por @Trauma: añadir los datos concretos de cada muro en un *array*. En tu caso, por lo que veo, añadirías esos datos extra a tu `Mao[]`.